WPF. Creating a Button template: binding the values ​of template elements
I've been working for a couple days to try to fully create a button style from an implementation that i have. I keep getting most of the way there, but am not able to fully configure it how i need to. The 2 buttons need to look the same. The first is my attempt to extract out the style, and the second is the button as it exists without a style.
I need to be able to set the following values: The Text/Content, image, background, foreground, and border brush (used by the image to determine color to show).

Given button definitions:
<Button Name="Row4_Column1"
            BorderBrush="{DynamicResource TextOnPrimaryBrush}"
            BorderThickness="0"
            Background="{DynamicResource PrimaryBrush}"
            Height="30"
            Width="100"
            Style="{DynamicResource RoundedButtonStyle}">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Viewbox Width="15"
                     Height="15">
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="trash-alt-regular" />
            </Viewbox>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="5,0,0,0"
                       Text="New" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>

    <Button Name="Row4_Column2"
    BorderBrush="{DynamicResource TextOnPrimaryBrush}"
    Height="30"
    Width="100"
    Background="{DynamicResource PrimaryBrush}">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                CornerRadius="15">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Viewbox Width="15" Height="15"> 
                            <StaticResource ResourceKey="trash-alt-regular" />
                        </Viewbox>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Margin="5,0,0,0"
                           Text="New" />
                    </StackPanel> 
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>

and an image definition:
<Viewbox x:Key="trash-alt-regular"
         x:Shared="False">
    <Path Data="M192 188v216c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12h-24c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12V188c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h24c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12zm100-12h-24c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12v216c0 6.627 5.373 12 12 12h24c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12V188c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12zm132-96c13.255 0 24 10.745 24 24v12c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12h-20v336c0 26.51-21.49 48-48 48H80c-26.51 0-48-21.49-48-48V128H12c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-12c0-13.255 10.745-24 24-24h74.411l34.018-56.696A48 48 0 0 1 173.589 0h100.823a48 48 0 0 1 41.16 23.304L349.589 80H424zm-269.611 0h139.223L276.16 50.913A6 6 0 0 0 271.015 48h-94.028a6 6 0 0 0-5.145 2.913L154.389 80zM368 128H80v330a6 6 0 0 0 6 6h276a6 6 0 0 0 6-6V128z"
          Fill="{Binding Path=BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Border}}}" />
</Viewbox>

Simply put, i need to create a rounded corner button. The foreground and background colors are bound to brushes defined in a dictionary. If the button is to use an image, the image will be in the format above (taken from fontawesome). Ultimately, I'd love to be able to just define the look and feel and be able to create a grid or stackpanel with the Viewbox and text defined how i want them oriented, but i can live with a locked in grid or stackpanel layout.
Here is my style starting point:
<Style x:Key="RoundedButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                        CornerRadius="15">
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


Regarding the Text property you can use a TemplateBinding to set the Content property of the button as the Text property of the TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}". Regarding the Viewbox you might be looking for a ContentPresenter

It is not clear from your explanations what exactly needs to be bound to what.
I am showing a solution based on this understanding of your explanations:

Viewbox binding:


<Viewbox Width="15" Height="15"> <!-- Needs to be bound -->

You need to create a square Viewbox with a Height equal to the button Height

StaticResource binding:


<StaticResource ResourceKey="AddSvg" /> <!-- Needs to be bound -->

"AddSvg" is a UI element that is declared in the parent resources. This element must be scaled by the ViewBox and it must be used by only one button.

TextBlock binding:


<TextBlock ... Text="New" /> <!-- Needs to be bound -->

"Text" must be bound to the Content property of the button.
My Example:
<Window x:Class="Core2024.SO.Jason.question79151704.BindingOfTemplateWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2024.SO.Jason.question79151704"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="BindingOfTemplateWindow" Height="150" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Border x:Key="AddSvg" Background="Green"
                Padding="5"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
            <TextBlock Text="Example"/>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="bytton.Template">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                CornerRadius="15">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Viewbox
                        Width="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}"
                        Height="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{DynamicResource AddSvg}"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Margin="5,0,0,0"
                           Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <UniformGrid>
        <Button BorderBrush="Red"
                Tag="Blue"
                Height="30" Width="100"
                Background="Coral"
                Template="{DynamicResource bytton.Template}"
                Content="Button Text"/>
        <Button BorderBrush="Yellow"
                Tag="Blue"
                Height="30" Width="100"
                Background="YellowGreen"
                Template="{DynamicResource bytton.Template}"
                Content="Text">
            <Button.Resources>
                <Grid x:Key="AddSvg">
                    <Ellipse Fill="Orange"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="X" Margin="2"/>
                </Grid>
            </Button.Resources>
        </Button>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>


Option after clarifying the details of the question:
<Window x:Class="Core2024.SO.Jason.question79151704.BindingOfTemplateWindowV1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2024.SO.Jason.question79151704"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="BindingOfTemplateWindowV1" Height="150" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Border x:Key="AddSvg" Background="Green"
                Padding="5"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
            <TextBlock Text="Example"/>
        </Border>
        <Geometry x:Key="trash-alt-regular">
            M192 188v216c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12h-24c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12V188c0-6.627
            5.373-12 12-12h24c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12zm100-12h-24c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12v216c0
            6.627 5.373 12 12 12h24c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12V188c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12zm132-96c13.255
            0 24 10.745 24 24v12c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12h-20v336c0 26.51-21.49 48-48 48H80c-26.51
            0-48-21.49-48-48V128H12c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-12c0-13.255 10.745-24 24-24h74.411l34.018-56.696A48
            48 0 0 1 173.589 0h100.823a48 48 0 0 1 41.16 23.304L349.589 80H424zm-269.611 0h139.223L276.16 50.913A6
            6 0 0 0 271.015 48h-94.028a6 6 0 0 0-5.145 2.913L154.389 80zM368 128H80v330a6
            6 0 0 0 6 6h276a6 6 0 0 0 6-6V128z
        </Geometry>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="bytton.Template">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    CornerRadius="15">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Viewbox Margin="5">
                        <Path Data="{DynamicResource trash-alt-regular}"
                              Fill="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" />
                    </Viewbox>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Margin="5,0,0,0"
                           Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="bytton.Template1">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    CornerRadius="{Binding ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=heightProxy}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <FrameworkElement x:Name="heightProxy"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                Grid.RowSpan="2">
                    <Viewbox Margin="5">
                        <Path Data="{DynamicResource trash-alt-regular}"
                              Fill="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" />
                    </Viewbox>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Margin="5,0,0,0"
                           Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
                </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <UniformGrid>
        <Button BorderBrush="Red"
                Tag="Blue"
                Height="30" Width="100"
                Background="Coral"
                Template="{DynamicResource bytton.Template}"
                Content="Button Text"/>
        <Button BorderBrush="Yellow"
                Tag="Blue"
                Height="50" Width="150"
                Background="YellowGreen"
                Template="{DynamicResource bytton.Template}"
                Content="Text">
            <Button.Resources>
                <Geometry x:Key="trash-alt-regular">
                    M433.109 23.694c-3.614-3.612-7.898-5.424-12.848-5.424c-4.948 0-9.226 1.812-12.847 5.424l-37.113 36.835
                    c-20.365-19.226-43.684-34.123-69.948-44.684C274.091 5.283 247.056 0.003 219.266 0.003c-52.344 0-98.022 15.843-137.042 47.536             C43.203 79.228 17.509 120.574 5.137 171.587v1.997c0 2.474 0.903 4.617 2.712 6.423c1.809 1.809 3.949 2.712 6.423 2.712h56.814             c4.189 0 7.042-2.19 8.566-6.565c7.993-19.032 13.035-30.166 15.131-33.403c13.322-21.698 31.023-38.734 53.103-51.106             c22.082-12.371 45.873-18.559 71.376-18.559c38.261 0 71.473 13.039 99.645 39.115l-39.406 39.397             c-3.607 3.617-5.421 7.902-5.421 12.851c0 4.948 1.813 9.231 5.421 12.847c3.621 3.617 7.905 5.424 12.854 5.424h127.906
                    c4.949 0 9.233-1.807 12.848-5.424c3.613-3.616 5.42-7.898 5.42-12.847V36.542C438.529 31.593 436.733 27.312 433.109 23.694z
                </Geometry>
            </Button.Resources>
        </Button>
        <Button BorderBrush="Yellow"
                Tag="Blue"
                Height="50" Width="150"
                Background="YellowGreen"
                Template="{DynamicResource bytton.Template1}"
                Content="Text">
            <Button.Resources>
                <Geometry x:Key="trash-alt-regular">
                    M433.109 23.694c-3.614-3.612-7.898-5.424-12.848-5.424c-4.948 0-9.226 1.812-12.847 5.424l-37.113 36.835
                    c-20.365-19.226-43.684-34.123-69.948-44.684C274.091 5.283 247.056 0.003 219.266 0.003c-52.344 0-98.022 15.843-137.042 47.536             C43.203 79.228 17.509 120.574 5.137 171.587v1.997c0 2.474 0.903 4.617 2.712 6.423c1.809 1.809 3.949 2.712 6.423 2.712h56.814             c4.189 0 7.042-2.19 8.566-6.565c7.993-19.032 13.035-30.166 15.131-33.403c13.322-21.698 31.023-38.734 53.103-51.106             c22.082-12.371 45.873-18.559 71.376-18.559c38.261 0 71.473 13.039 99.645 39.115l-39.406 39.397             c-3.607 3.617-5.421 7.902-5.421 12.851c0 4.948 1.813 9.231 5.421 12.847c3.621 3.617 7.905 5.424 12.854 5.424h127.906
                    c4.949 0 9.233-1.807 12.848-5.424c3.613-3.616 5.42-7.898 5.42-12.847V36.542C438.529 31.593 436.733 27.312 433.109 23.694z
                </Geometry>
            </Button.Resources>
        </Button>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>



the images are viewboxes,

Using Data Template:
<Window x:Class="Core2024.SO.Jason.question79151704.BindingOfTemplateWindowV2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2024.SO.Jason.question79151704"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="BindingOfTemplateWindowV2" Height="150" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Border x:Key="AddSvg" Background="Green"
                Padding="5"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
            <TextBlock Text="Example"/>
        </Border>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="trash-alt-regular">
            <Viewbox Margin="5">
                <Path
                    Fill="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Border}}}">
                    <Path.Data>
                        M192 188v216c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12h-24c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12V188c0-6.627
                        5.373-12 12-12h24c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12zm100-12h-24c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12v216c0
                        6.627 5.373 12 12 12h24c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12V188c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12zm132-96c13.255
                        0 24 10.745 24 24v12c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12h-20v336c0 26.51-21.49 48-48 48H80c-26.51
                        0-48-21.49-48-48V128H12c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-12c0-13.255 10.745-24 24-24h74.411l34.018-56.696A48
                        48 0 0 1 173.589 0h100.823a48 48 0 0 1 41.16 23.304L349.589 80H424zm-269.611 0h139.223L276.16 50.913A6
                        6 0 0 0 271.015 48h-94.028a6 6 0 0 0-5.145 2.913L154.389 80zM368 128H80v330a6
                        6 0 0 0 6 6h276a6 6 0 0 0 6-6V128z
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </Viewbox>
        </DataTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="bytton.Template">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    CornerRadius="15">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource trash-alt-regular}"/>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Margin="5,0,0,0"
                           Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="bytton.Template1">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    CornerRadius="{Binding ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=heightProxy}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <FrameworkElement x:Name="heightProxy"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                Grid.RowSpan="2">
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource trash-alt-regular}"/>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Margin="5,0,0,0"
                           Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <UniformGrid Columns="2" Rows="1">
        <Button BorderBrush="Red"
                Tag="Blue"
                Height="30" Width="100"
                Background="Coral"
                Template="{DynamicResource bytton.Template}"
                Content="Button Text"/>
        <UniformGrid Columns="1">
            <FrameworkElement.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="trash-alt-regular">
                    <Viewbox Margin="5">
                        <Path
                            Fill="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Border}}}">
                            <Path.Data>
                                M433.109 23.694c-3.614-3.612-7.898-5.424-12.848-5.424c-4.948 0-9.226 1.812-12.847 5.424l-37.113 36.835
                                c-20.365-19.226-43.684-34.123-69.948-44.684C274.091 5.283 247.056 0.003 219.266 0.003c-52.344 0-98.022 15.843-137.042 47.536
                                C43.203 79.228 17.509 120.574 5.137 171.587v1.997c0 2.474 0.903 4.617 2.712 6.423c1.809 1.809 3.949 2.712 6.423 2.712h56.814
                                c4.189 0 7.042-2.19 8.566-6.565c7.993-19.032 13.035-30.166 15.131-33.403c13.322-21.698 31.023-38.734 53.103-51.106
                                c22.082-12.371 45.873-18.559 71.376-18.559c38.261 0 71.473 13.039 99.645 39.115l-39.406 39.397
                                c-3.607 3.617-5.421 7.902-5.421 12.851c0 4.948 1.813 9.231 5.421 12.847c3.621 3.617 7.905 5.424 12.854 5.424h127.906
                                c4.949 0 9.233-1.807 12.848-5.424c3.613-3.616 5.42-7.898 5.42-12.847V36.542C438.529 31.593 436.733 27.312 433.109 23.694z
                            </Path.Data>
                        </Path>
                    </Viewbox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </FrameworkElement.Resources>
            <Button BorderBrush="Yellow"
                Tag="Blue"
                Height="50" Width="150"
                Background="YellowGreen"
                Template="{DynamicResource bytton.Template}"
                Content="Text">
            </Button>
            <Button BorderBrush="Yellow"
                Tag="Blue"
                Height="50" Width="150"
                Background="YellowGreen"
                Template="{DynamicResource bytton.Template1}"
                Content="Text">
            </Button>
        </UniformGrid>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>

Or the option with a common UI element in resources. In my opinion, this is not the right way to do it. But if you have such a condition in the task, then you can use it.
<Window x:Class="Core2024.SO.Jason.question79151704.BindingOfTemplateWindowV3"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2024.SO.Jason.question79151704"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="BindingOfTemplateWindowV2" Height="150" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Border x:Key="AddSvg" Background="Green"
                Padding="5"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
            <TextBlock Text="Example"/>
        </Border>
        <Viewbox x:Key="trash-alt-regular"
                 x:Shared="False"
                 Margin="5">
            <Path
                Fill="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Border}}}">
                <Path.Data>
                    M192 188v216c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12h-24c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12V188c0-6.627
                    5.373-12 12-12h24c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12zm100-12h-24c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12v216c0
                    6.627 5.373 12 12 12h24c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12V188c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12zm132-96c13.255
                    0 24 10.745 24 24v12c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12h-20v336c0 26.51-21.49 48-48 48H80c-26.51
                    0-48-21.49-48-48V128H12c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-12c0-13.255 10.745-24 24-24h74.411l34.018-56.696A48
                    48 0 0 1 173.589 0h100.823a48 48 0 0 1 41.16 23.304L349.589 80H424zm-269.611 0h139.223L276.16 50.913A6
                    6 0 0 0 271.015 48h-94.028a6 6 0 0 0-5.145 2.913L154.389 80zM368 128H80v330a6
                    6 0 0 0 6 6h276a6 6 0 0 0 6-6V128z
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </Viewbox>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="bytton.Template">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    CornerRadius="15">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{DynamicResource trash-alt-regular}"/>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Margin="5,0,0,0"
                           Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="bytton.Template1">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    CornerRadius="{Binding ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=heightProxy}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <FrameworkElement x:Name="heightProxy"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                Grid.RowSpan="2">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{DynamicResource trash-alt-regular}"/>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Margin="5,0,0,0"
                           Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <UniformGrid Columns="2" Rows="1">
        <Button BorderBrush="Red"
                Tag="Blue"
                Height="30" Width="100"
                Background="Coral"
                Template="{DynamicResource bytton.Template}"
                Content="Button Text"/>
        <UniformGrid Columns="1">
            <FrameworkElement.Resources>
                <Viewbox x:Key="trash-alt-regular"
                     x:Shared="False"
                     Margin="5">
                    <Path
                        Fill="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Border}}}">
                        <Path.Data>
                            M433.109 23.694c-3.614-3.612-7.898-5.424-12.848-5.424c-4.948 0-9.226 1.812-12.847 5.424l-37.113 36.835
                                c-20.365-19.226-43.684-34.123-69.948-44.684C274.091 5.283 247.056 0.003 219.266 0.003c-52.344 0-98.022 15.843-137.042 47.536
                                C43.203 79.228 17.509 120.574 5.137 171.587v1.997c0 2.474 0.903 4.617 2.712 6.423c1.809 1.809 3.949 2.712 6.423 2.712h56.814
                                c4.189 0 7.042-2.19 8.566-6.565c7.993-19.032 13.035-30.166 15.131-33.403c13.322-21.698 31.023-38.734 53.103-51.106
                                c22.082-12.371 45.873-18.559 71.376-18.559c38.261 0 71.473 13.039 99.645 39.115l-39.406 39.397
                                c-3.607 3.617-5.421 7.902-5.421 12.851c0 4.948 1.813 9.231 5.421 12.847c3.621 3.617 7.905 5.424 12.854 5.424h127.906
                                c4.949 0 9.233-1.807 12.848-5.424c3.613-3.616 5.42-7.898 5.42-12.847V36.542C438.529 31.593 436.733 27.312 433.109 23.694z
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                </Viewbox>
            </FrameworkElement.Resources>
            <Button BorderBrush="Yellow"
                Tag="Blue"
                Height="50" Width="150"
                Background="YellowGreen"
                Template="{DynamicResource bytton.Template}"
                Content="Text">
            </Button>
            <Button BorderBrush="Yellow"
                Tag="Blue"
                Height="50" Width="150"
                Background="YellowGreen"
                Template="{DynamicResource bytton.Template1}"
                Content="Text">
            </Button>
        </UniformGrid>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>

For both last options we get the same image:

In this version, I am confused by <Path Fill="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Border}}}">. In my opinion, it is not quite right when the Data Template "knows" in what layout it will be used, what mandatory ancestors it must have and at what level.

I can see where the lack of clarity is. I will update the question as best i can. The 'AddSvg' is the name of an SVG wrapped in a viewbox.

@Jason
"SVG" can't be displayed directly in WPF. You use some kind of helper control to display it. And how exactly you display it is also important for a full understanding of the task.

See my edits above.

@Jason
I have supplemented my answer. Please see this supplement.

I see what you're doing, however, the images are viewboxes, therefore i can't use them as a geometry. it does get me closer, but I am still not over the finish line

@Jason
If you want to set an image (icon) using UI elements, it is better to use a data template for this.
See my answer for another implementation option.

If you want to use the same Button Template for all buttons, but have the ability to set different keys in the button itself, then I think you will need an Attached Property with the logic for creating a DynamicResource.
